# AutoMapper MapFrom has no effect

Tags: c#, automapper

Edited: To add constructor with parameters information.

I am using AutoMapper Version 9.0 and .Net Core 2.1
The following unit test should change `stockRecord.ClosePrice`'s value, but it does not if the second constructor is present.  Once comment out the second constructor `closePrice` will have the correct value of 100.

StockRecord Class

```
[DynamoDBTable("StockRecord")]
public class StockRecord
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string TickerSymbol { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBRangeKey]
    public DateTime TradingDay { get; private set; }

    public float OpenPrice { get; private set; }
    public float ClosePrice { get; private set; }
    public float DayHighestPrice { get; private set; }
    public float DayLowestPrice { get; private set; }

    public StockRecord() {}

    // add this constructor below will make the unit test below fail, ClosePrice will stay value of 20
    // Once Comment out this constructor, unit test will pass, ClosePrice value will change to 100
    public StockRecord(string tickerSymbol, DateTime tradingDay, float openPrice, float closePrice, float dayHighestPrice, float dayLowestPrice)
    {
        TickerSymbol = tickerSymbol;
        TradingDay = tradingDay;
        OpenPrice = openPrice;
        ClosePrice = closePrice;
        DayHighestPrice = dayHighestPrice;
        DayLowestPrice = dayLowestPrice;
    }       
}
```

StockRecordDto Class

```
public class StockRecordDto
{
    public string TickerSymbol { get; set; }
    public DateTime TradingDay { get; set; }
    public float OpenPrice { get; set; }
    public float ClosePrice { get; set; }
    public float DayHighestPrice { get; set; }
    public float DayLowestPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Unit Test

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<StockRecord, StockRecordDto>()
        .ForMember(dst => dst.ClosePrice, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.ClosePrice > 0 ? 300 : 400))
        .ReverseMap()
        .ForMember(dst => dst.ClosePrice, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.ClosePrice > 0 ? 100 : 200));
    });
    configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

    var stockRecordDto = new StockRecordDto
    {
        TickerSymbol = "ticker 01",
        TradingDay = DateTime.Now,
        OpenPrice = 10,
        ClosePrice = 20,
        DayHighestPrice = 30,
        DayLowestPrice = 5
    };

    StockRecord stockRecord = mapper.Map<StockRecord>(stockRecordDto);
    Assert.Equal(100, stockRecord.ClosePrice);
}
```

According autoMapper's docs `stockRecord.ClosePrice should change to 100.  But it is still 20.
I spend the entire afternoon on this but still couldn't figure it out.
I could replace the constructor with a factory method but I still do not understand why the constructor with parameters will case the problem.

If this is a bug, I will post an issue at AutoMapper's github.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change `DayLowestPrice`, then in your mapping use as destination field `DayLowestPrice` instead of `ClosePrice`:

```
cfg.CreateMap<StockRecord, StockRecordDto>()
        .ForMember(dst => dst.DayLowestPrice, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.ClosePrice > 0 ? 300 : 400))
        .ReverseMap()
        .ForMember(dst => dst.DayLowestPrice, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.ClosePrice > 0 ? 100 : 200));
```

**Edit**:

Since you have a constructor with parameters, it's being used to create StockRecord. So you can specify explicitly mapping for your constructor member via `FromCtorParam`:

```
cfg.CreateMap<StockRecord, StockRecordDto>()
  .ForMember(dst => dst.DayLowestPrice, op => op.MapFrom(src => src.ClosePrice > 0 ? 300 : 400))
  .ReverseMap()
  .ForCtorParam("closePrice", op => op.MapFrom(src => src.ClosePrice > 0 ? 100 : 200));
```

to speficy how your object needs to be contructed. You can find more info about why it behaves like this on [github](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/633).

**Edit2**:

You can also use `ConstructUsing`, but in this case you should make your properties readonly (remove `private set;` from properties) and specify all constructor parameters. In this case you can avoid hardcoding constructor parameter name.

```
public class StockRecord
{
       ***

    public float ClosePrice { get; }

       ***
}

cfg.CreateMap<StockRecordDto, StockRecord>()
  .ConstructUsing(s => new StockRecord(s.TickerSymbol, s.TradingDay, s.OpenPrice, s.ClosePrice > 0 ? 100 : 200, s.DayHighestPrice, s.DayLowestPrice));
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean ClosePrice, I copied the wrong text when I first post the question.  Have updated the question.

Comment: Copy pasting your code it works fine for me, ClosePrice is changed to 100. Since you haven't provided record classes I can only guess, that you have no setter or private setter on your `ClosePrice` member of the `StockRecord`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I updated the question with the classes.  I also find out that, it was the constructor with parameters was causing the problems, Once I commented out the second constructor, the unit test will pass.  Yet, I just do not understand why the constructor will cause the problem.  Should I need a day way or mapping?

Comment: I also tested, even if I make all the properties public by taking "private" out for my setters from StockRecord class as long as the constructor with parameters is there, the unit test will fail.

Comment: You can check my edit and also look at [Construction](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Construction.html) page from docs.

Comment: Thanks, using ForCtorParam does solve the problem, but with ForCtorParam(), I need to hard code "closePrice", which I do not feel very comfortable with.

after reading the Docs, I see that one can use DisableConstructorMapping() instead.  But is it possible to apply DisableConstructorMapping() to one model class only instead of the entire configuration for all the mapping model class?

Comment: I don't think that you can DisableConstructorMappings per mapping, but you can create different mapping configurations, and have 2 kind of mappers. Or maybe you can use `ConstructUsing`, to avoid having constructor name hardcoded.